# Problems uninstalling NetBeans 7.3.1 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, uninstall, netbeans

I am  having problems trying to uninstall *NetBeans 7.3.1* on Ubuntu 12.04.
When I run the uninstaller, it shows the message:

```
cannot create local directory: /root/.nbi
```

Someone knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

it have been worked for me.so you may try

1. go to terminal(<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>)
2. type `cd /usr/local/netbeans-7.3.1`
3. type `sudo sh uninstall.sh`
4. password:

then it will work.

Comment: Why `sh`? And why `cd`? `sudo /usr/local/netbeans-7.3.1/uninstall.sh` should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps:

1.Open terminal

```
  **(ctrl + alt +t)**
```

2.Go to netbeans installation directory

```
  **cd /usr/local/netbeanc8.*/**
```

3.Type following command

```
  **su**
```

and enter password

4.Run uninstall.sh script

```
  **sh uninstall.sh**
```

5.Now go to Home directory and make sure you delete following folders

```
  **netbeans8.*   .nbi    .netbeans**
```

To uninstall netbeans completely step 5 is very important. If you skip                step 5 and then try to install netbeans again you will see most of the components of the netbeans are already installed. So to completely remove netbeans follow above all the steps.